# Visual Studio is not reading my dll? (as a namespace)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have created a game that includes a-lot of methods listed in another class...
So I'd like to use this class globally, so I stored it in a DLL (to be able to use it in several other projects)

But somehow, Visual Studio is not finding the namespace of that DLL that I referenced!

[image: Here's an image]

Is there anything that I did wrong? The namespace of the 'fncs' DLL is also called 'fncs'...
Both of them have been created in the same version of .NET...
Thanks in advance!

The DLL:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace fncs {
    class io {
        public static bool write(string dir, object[] obj) {
            try {
                File.WriteAllLines(dir, ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)obj).Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            } return true;
        }
        public static string read(string dir) {
            StreamReader r = new StreamReader(dir);
            return r.ReadToEnd();
        }
        public static void saveToServer(string x, string y) {
            // hidden
        }
    }
    class rc {
        public static void echo(object obj) {
            Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
        }
        public static string get() {
            return Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class math {
        public static int add(int a, int b) {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
    class web {

        public static string getWebContent(string url) {
            WebClient c = new WebClient();
            string s;
            try {
                s = c.DownloadString(url);
            } catch (WebException w) {
                return w.ToString();
            } return s;
        }

        public static string OpenSQL() {
            SQLConnection SQL = new SQLConnection();
            return SQL.BindStatus();
        }

        public static string post(string Url, params string[] postdata) {
            string result = string.Empty;
            string data = string.Empty;

            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();

            if (postdata.Length % 2 != 0) {
                Console.WriteLine("Parameters must be even , \"user\" , \"value\" , ... etc");
                return string.Empty;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < postdata.Length; i += 2) {
                data += string.Format("&{0}={1}", postdata[i], postdata[i + 1]);
            }

            data = data.Remove(0, 1);

            byte[] bytesarr = ascii.GetBytes(data);
            try {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Url);

                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = bytesarr.Length;

                System.IO.Stream streamwriter = request.GetRequestStream();
                streamwriter.Write(bytesarr, 0, bytesarr.Length);
                streamwriter.Close();

                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                streamwriter = response.GetResponseStream();

                System.IO.StreamReader streamread = new System.IO.StreamReader(streamwriter);
                result = streamread.ReadToEnd();
                streamread.Close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    class SQLConnection {
        public string conn_bind;
        public SQLConnection() {
            //hidden
        }
        public string BindStatus() {
            return conn_bind;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excuse me for using this title if it's wrong, but I don't know the correct words to use in such a case... I'm 15 years old after all.

Comment: Says your image is empty. Can you just paste it on here?

Comment: Oh, sorry, fixed now...

Comment: That depends upon what is the target framework version of the dll and current project. If current project version is less than dll target fw version this will happen

Comment: can you show your dll code...

Comment: Make sure you are targeting the right framework, common problem is your fncs is a .net 4.0 dll, but your project you are working on is .net 4.0 Client Profile. Change it to .NET 4.0

Comment: @Sriram I doubt it's a version problem because I have coded both, the game and the DLL from scratch in the same day.

Comment: Hm, not sure how to do that though, let me show you my DLL code

Comment: So just check the target framework version of both assemblies and share it with us

Comment: tried to mark your DLL classes as PUBLIC?

Comment: Stupid question: How to check for Target Framework? (sorry, I'm a plain noob)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In the solution explorer, right click on the reference you have added for fncs.
2. Select "View in object browser". That will bring up all the assemblies which the project sees.
3. Within the tree select the fncs and verify in the lower right window, that yes this is the assembly you think should be included. (most likely is).
4. Open up fncs and look at the namespaces.
5. There should be an FNCS namespace, if not go back to the fncs
   project and determine why.
6. If there is a FNCS namespace, verify that there is a class within
   fncs which you target and again examine it in the right windows to verify it is what you want.

----update----

Your class needs to be public. The default is internal which means only within the assembly can it be viewed. Once you make it public and rebuild, your other project should see it.

Comment: Well, here's an image: http://puu.sh/4RFC5.png there is no namespaces, any idea why? Even though there is one in the DLL itself :o

Comment: Oh thank you... Looks like this worked! Thanks a bunch! Looks like my classes were not public...

Comment: @John wished I had the internet/C# when I was 15...all I had was Basic on the schools computer teletype console to the mainframe! :-)